# How to get perpendicular vectors given a line segment

Tags: math, graphics, vector

How to get point A, B , C, and D?

if AB and CD are perpendicular to p0p1.

Assume p0A, p0B, p1C, and p1D have normalized length

[image]

Comment: Do you know the coordinates of the points p0 and p1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direction of the line is given by `d = normalize(p1 - p0)`. To calculate a perpendicular vector we can use the cross product with `(0, 0, 1)`. Which results in:

```
d_left = (-d.y, d.x)
d_right = (d.y, -d.x)
```

You haven't said how your coordinate system is aligned, so `d_left` might become `d_right` and vice versa.

You then get the desired points with:

```
A = p0 + d_left
B = p0 + d_right
C = p1 + d_left
D = p1 + d_right
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `rotate(p,d)` is a operator to rotate `p` vector `d` angle.

Then if the inclination of `p0p1` with positive `x-axis` is `x`. Then,

A = p0 + rotate(p1-p0,pi/2)/|p1-p0|
B = p0 + rotate(p1-p0,-pi/2)/|p1-p0|
C = p1 + rotate(p1-p0,pi/2)/|p1-p0|
D = p1 + rotate(p1-p0,-pi/2)/|p1-p0|