# Find perpendicular segments at ends of segment

Tags: php, c++, math, graphics, geometry

[image: find perpendicular segments]

Hello, 
I'm making an application in which I have the points (p0,p1), and need to find the points for perpendicular segments at the end of (p0,p1)... namely, (A,B) and (C,D), which are of length $len.
There is a similar question to this one in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831159/how-to-get-perpendicular-vectors-given-a-line-segment), but unfortunately I am not sure about how to interpret the answer...
I'm using php for this project, but the solution can be in any language as I can translate it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
(A-E)/(l/2) = (p1-F)/L
```

and so on...

Comment: That seems to apply to the lengths... How can I get the points? For example... How can I get point A?

Comment: `(A-E)` is `(po[x] - A[x])`, `(p1-F)` is `(p1[x] - p0[x])`. I hope you find `A[x]` from there

Comment: By the way, `B[x] = 2*po[x] - A[x]`

Comment: @JeanAlesi you did it?

Comment: Yes.. This actually helped me find an even better solution than what I had initially visualized. Thank you.

Comment: @JeanAlesi it is very well. Good luck!